# pandas for loop, works on small dataframes hangs up on large

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a zip code table to make a county table for a choroplot. My code works fine when I give it a small toy example, but when I give it the dataframe it hangs up. I can't share the dataframe but it's +/- 70,000 zip codes, encoded as strings and the values can be correct zipcodes, non numerical string, or numerical string that isn't a correct zipcode, each in string format. This is the code:

```
# import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# load customer email table
df = pd.read_csv('customer_April2018.csv', encoding='latin-1')

# load zip code table
zc = pd.read_csv('us_postal_codes.csv', encoding='latin-1')

def zip_toCounty(zip):
    for i, row in zc.iterrows():
        try:
            if int(zip) == zc['ZipCode'].loc[i] : return zc['County'].loc[i]    
        except ValueError : return 'No County'
    return 'No County'

g = lambda s : zip_toCounty(s)

df['County']=df['ZipCode'].apply(g)

df.to_csv('join_test.csv',index=False)
```

I don't get errors but the estimated completion time is 40+ hours which is completely unreasonable given the size of the data. I must be using something wrong, how can I speed up the processing? One person suggested a hash function, is that the best option here?

Comment: Can you share some samples of your dataframes. Doesn't this look like a typical map problem like  `df['ZipCode'].map(zc.set_index(0)[1])`

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't do some kind of join here between the two dataframes?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with.map(). I'll look into that now. 

I tried to use a join command before and it didn't work. I used the solution below but that hasn't worked. I suspect it is because the two ZipCode columns have different data types. I'm working changing one to the other now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do without the loop and function altogether and just merge the datasets on the ZipCode column:

```
new_df = pd.merge(df, zc, how="left", left_on="ZipCode", right_on="ZipCode")
```

Comment: This leaves NaN in the whole County column for the table. The ZipCode column in zc is stored as <class 'numpy.int64'> and the one in df is stored as <class 'float'> does that matter?

Comment: @user40551 Yes that's probably why - you can use `df["ZipCode"] = df["ZipCode"].astype(int)` to convert it to the same data type.

Comment: @user40551 actually I just tested and you can merge a float column with an int column, so presuming there are some matching ZipCode values between the two DFs then the merge should work without converting the data types. If you're still having problems I suggest posting an example few rows from the 2 data frames

Comment: These are from my DB :  
`22                      NaN`  
`51                    33131`
`56                90291-391`
`112       Tamarac, Fl 33321`
`121         Ponce, PR 00716`

These are from the ZipCode table i'm using: 
`ZipCode Place Name State State Abbreviation County Latitude Longitude`  
`0 501 Holtsville New York NY Suffolk 40.8154 -73.0451`
`1 544 Holtsville New York NY Suffolk 40.8154 -73.0451`
`2 1001 Agawam Massachusetts MA Hampden 42.0702 -72.6227`

Comment: Hmm well it looks like your zipcode file doesn't have full zip codes stored - for example 501 isn't the zip code in Long Island, it's 11501 (I just happen to know this!) So you may need to correct the data in this file first so that the zip code formats match...

Comment: I have Nassau and Suffolk counties as having 11xxx zip codes, I double checked for Holtsville and they actually do have the 501 zip. I've also confirmed it for a number of other addresses I've had in the past. I can't vouch for the entire table but t least with respect to the places I've lived they are correct in the table, and to the places you mention I have double checked those. :(

Comment: The point is that the zip codes are in different formats in your 2 different tables - the full 5 figures zip codes in your DB, and 3 digits in your zip codes file. Therefore any merge between the 2 tables won't find any matches. You need to amend the format in one table and then merge on the amended format.